# Force process to always be in RAM on Windows

Tags: windows, memory, dma

I would like the process I'm using, to never be in the Windows page file. This isn't for performance, rather I wish to use DMA to monitor it. If the used virtual address space isn't in RAM I can't access it. I have tried disabling the page file on windows however the virtual address space does still not appear in the VAD for RAM. Any suggestions about how I might force a process into ram would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the problem occuring even while the process is actively running? (It cannot really _be_ anywhere else but physical RAM while running...)

Comment: @user1686 Yeah it is, some sections of the dll I'm inspecting don't seem to be accessible. I'm using pcileech I guess it could be an issue with that instead?